# get each row with max values of group

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I got the following table:

```
col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | timestamp
-------------------------------------
  1  | ...  | ...  | ...  | 12:01
  1  | ...  | ...  | ...  | 12:40
  2  | ...  | ...  | ...  | 11:00
  2  | ...  | ...  | ...  | 13:00
  2  | ...  | ...  | ...  | 12:22
  3  | ...  | ...  | ...  | 16:00
  3  | ...  | ...  | ...  | 12:10
```

i want to get each row with max timestamp values grouped by column 1. this means the result have to be the following:

```
col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | timestamp
-------------------------------------
  1  | ...  | ...  | ...  | 12:40
  2  | ...  | ...  | ...  | 13:00
  3  | ...  | ...  | ...  | 16:00
```

my following query works:

```
SELECT col1, MAX(timestamp)
FROM table
GROUP BY col1
```

but not this:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4, MAX(timestamp)
FROM table
GROUP BY col1
```

Comment: do columns 2 to 4 contain nothing? If not post some sample data

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieving the last record in each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give a **`row number`** based on partition by **`col1`** column and in the descending order of **`timestamp`** column. And the select the rows having **`rn = 1`**.

**Query**

```
;with cte as(
    select [rn] = row_number() over(
        partition by [col1]
        order by [timestamp] desc
    ), *
    from your_table_name
)
select [col1], [col2], [col3], [col4], [timestamp]
from cte
where [rn] = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could get the maximum timestamp the way it works for you and then join with the initial table to get the other values, like this:

```
select t.col1, t.col2, t.col3, t.col4, tmax.max_ts
from table t join   (
                            select col1, max(timestamp) max_ts
                            from table
                            group by col1
                         ) tmax on tmax.col1 = t.col1 and tmax.max_ts = t.timestamp
```